# Issues in window.location.href for SMS messaging in windows platform

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, windows-phone

I am using the following command in Javascript to send SMS messages.

```
document.location.href = "sms:[phone number goes here]?body=" + "hello test message";
```

This is working fine in Android platform and i'm trying to implement the same in windows platform, it is asking to install some third party app from store to do.

I am using cordova 3.7.1 for windows phone.

Any suggestion is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

SmsComposeTask launcher is required to send SMS message on wp8. You can add this plugin https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin to do that.

Or implement it in your own plugin based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394005(v=vs.105).aspx